# Is it possible to set a custom ListView in a ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I designed a ListView subclass, but I don't know if it's better to extend from Fragment and return my custom ListView from `onCreateView` or (if possible) to let the ListFragment to handle the it?

Answer (score 0):

overriding onCreateView would be the way to do it.

That said:
-If you're supplying your own custom ListView, why are you using ListFragment?
-What customizations are you including in your ListView?  Often the default ListView works, and customizations go into a ListAdapter.

Comment: I was trying to achieve [this](http://proandroiddev.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/android-design-tip-drop-shadows-on.html) effect, for applying drop shadows.

Comment: And I am trying to use this: http://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-overscroll-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

From information extracted from [Android SDK: Using Custom View In XML Based Layout](http://permadi.com/blog/2010/03/android-sdk-using-custom-view-in-xml-based-layout/), it is easy to answer your question:

In your xml layout file, instead using "ListView", just put the name (with packages) in the xml file. An example:

**Before:**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:background="@color/list_background"
               android:layout_weight="1" />

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@color/no_data_list_background"
               android:text="No data" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

**After:**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <com.mycompany.BounceListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:background="@color/list_background"
               android:layout_weight="1" />

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@color/no_data_list_background"
               android:text="No data" />
 </LinearLayout>
```